# In parallax scrolling Identify the section visible on window

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I was trying with parallax loading, I understand the basic functionality and did one Example.

Below code works well for one page website. What I do here is when page is scrolled I change position of element. But I'm stuck at point where suppose I have another 3, 4 sections on page when page is scrolled to some position then corresponding section we need to change.

**How would I come to know that page has been scrolled to third section so that I can specifical move element for that section?**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        parallax();
    });
});


function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

    console.log('scrolled'+scrolled+' and after multiplay='+scrolled*0.5);
    $('.group_float').css('top',-(scrolled*0.7)+'px');
    var fontSize = parseInt($(".floating_title").css("font-size"));
    fontSize = fontSize - 1+ "px";
    //$("body").css({'font-size':fontSize});
    $('.floating_title').css({'font-size':fontSize});
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check scrollspy `http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/`

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function returns true or false based on the fact if a particular element is visible  on viewport or not.You could use it to check if the user has scrolled to a particular session

```
    function isOnScreen(e) {
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
    var bounds = e.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + e.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + e.outerHeight();
    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom <                           bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
    };
```

Just use the ID or class name of the third session or fourth session as per your requirement and see if the element is on screen.This could be extended to 'n' elements

```
      if (isOnScreen($('.thirdSessionClassName')))
                {
                   // YOUR CODE TO CHANGE SESSION //
                }
      else if (isOnScreen($('.fourthSessionClassName')))
                {
                   // YOUR CODE TO CHANGE SESSION //
                }
```